# Error "Forbidden" when .htaccess present?

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2

I'm running Apache2 webserver with nginx proxy, as soon as I place a .htaccess inside my folder I get

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access blabla on this server.
```

In my httpd.conf I have     `AllowOverride All` set.

the content of the .htaccess doesn't matter, it's just as soon as the file is present, I get the Forbidden error.

What's the problem here ?

Comment: Check the server's error log, it should have more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it definately depends on what your .htaccess contains.. HTTP/1.0 Forbidden however leads me to thinking you either have

1. no `DirectoryIndex` present or you override it - and also have `Options -Indexes`
2. you have some symbolic linkage and `Options +FollowSymlinks` in your local htaccess messes things up

For proper symlinkage to work with apache then the containing directory must have eXecute permission for the apache user.

Sample output `ls -la` from my drupal /sites/ folder:

drwxr-xr-**x** 4 mschr root   4096  9 may 15:41 .

drwxr-xr-x 9 mschr apache 4096 22 may 21:18 ..

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root     16  4 may 08:16 all -> /etc/drupal/all/